# Looking for a weakly Lindel\"of Tychonoff Moore non-ccc space

Tags: gn.general-topology, counterexamples

Is there a weakly Lindel\"of Tychonoff Moore non-ccc space?

Note that here ccc denotes the countable chain condition; a space $X$ is called weakly Linde\"of if for any open cover $\mathcal U$ of $X$ there is a counable subset $\mathcal V \subset \mathcal U$ such that $\bigcup \mathcal V$ is dense in $X$.

I have a regular example in hand; but i'm looking for a Tychononff example of a weakly Lindel\"of non-ccc space?

Comment: Could you describe your "regular" example? Maybe it is Tychonoff automatically? Because existing examples of regular non-Tychonoff spaces are not Moore.

Comment: Let $X$ be a regular first countable Lindel\"of non-ccc space. Then the space $M(X)$ is the regular example, where $M(X)$ is the Moore Machine( see http://xueshu.baidu.com/s?wd=paperuri%3A%28a3ffad6b618a2d7beca11fa62dc66a13%29&filter=sc_long_sign&tn=SE_xueshusource_2kduw22v&sc_vurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencedirect.com%2Fscience%2Farticle%2Fpii%2F0016660X74900257&ie=utf-8&sc_us=13010694686562706088)

Comment: It is a good question under which conditions the Moore Machine prserves the Tychonoff property of spaces.